# Ayuda, Como Inserto un script a una tabla que ya tiene datos

Tags: sql-server

Era si me pueden ayudar con la siguiente duda:

Genere un script  en SQL server de únicamente los datos de la tabla agencias (id_agencia,nombre).
La intención es usar ese script en otra tabla de otra base de datos que también se llama agencia y usa la misma estructura.

Mi problema es que esa otra tabla ya tiene datos y el script que genere viene con los id por lo que si yo lo  ejecuto habrá un error de datos duplicados

Este es el script que genere con la opción de "generate scripts" de SQL server:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

----"Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AGENCIAS'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AGENCIAS'."

Por lo que quería saber como podría importar esos scripts sin que tenga en cuenta los id iguales o como podría insertar esos id iguales pero reemplazándolos.

Mi tabla es identity así que el id es autoincrementable.

Comment: insetalos en una nueva tabla y despues hace un inset desde esa a la vieja tabla sin incluir la columna que no queres

Comment: No, no puedo borrarlos por eso no he podido hacerlo :(

Comment: gbianchi podría funcionar, seria como unificar los datos de ambas tablas, voy a intentarlo gracias

Answer (score 0):

Listo ya encontré la solución,

Toca exportar la tabla vieja a un excel luego quitar la columna del id en el excel
luego desde el mismo sql server importar el archivo a la nueva tabla con eso no dará error con las llaves duplicadas y quedaran los datos de ambas tablas unificados.

Esto solo funciona por que el primary_key de mi tabla es identity.

Comment: Y porque a excel y no directamente a la base de datos? siguiendo esa logica, modifica tu script y quita la columna id de ahi...

Comment: Porque son como 20 columnas y 343 registros creo que me pareció mas fácil hacerlo desde excel.